# dbc toast appears behind dash datatable

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a dash datatable with fixed column headers.  I am using dbc Toasts to display messages.  When the Toasts get down to where the datatable is they are behind the datatable.  I have tried style={'position': 'relative', 'zindex': 1111} in the Toast but it seems that no number for the zindex is high enough to get it on top.  How can I make the Toasts show up on top of the datatable?

Comment: Can you share code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: It would be hard for me to simplify down to a postable code size.  I think it has something to do with the way I am displaying the toast. I put the toasts in a html.Div that I use a style={'position': 'fixed', 'top': 10, 'right': 10, 'width': 350} to display all of the toasts in the top right corner.  When I put the Toasts in the container, it doesn't seem to matter that I use a style={'position': 'relative', 'zindex': 1111}.  When I change the position to fixed and add zindex in the toast container, the toasts no longer are in the top right corner, they are in the bottom left corner.

Comment: When I have several Toasts in the top right corner, the only part of the toasts that are hidden is where the fixed datatable column headings and filter row are.  Is there a way to fix the toast container to the top right corner and not have the column headers hide part of them?